# Automatically Importing dependency classes in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Sublime text is one of my favourite IDEs but importing Classes from other maven dependencies reduces my efficiency and productivity, Is there any Plugin that is available to automatically import a maven dependency class? I found a [maven plugin for SublimeText2](https://coderwall.com/p/etesrq/how-to-set-up-maven-in-sublime-text) which I found out is obsolete and not compatible with SublimeText3 although the plugin just helps to build, It still does not solve my issue.

1. Is there any **Auto Import** Plugin for SublimeText3
2. Or rather is there any plugin that automatically import Spring Dependencies
3. If not can it be done and what are the procedures

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since this question has been asked, but you may try PHP Companion. Here's the link to the package on GitHub: https://github.com/erichard/SublimePHPCompanion

Once the package is installed, key shortcuts should be manually set.